# Why do radiators need bleeding? Where does the air come from?

Tags: central-heating, radiator

I had to bleed a radiator for the first time recently. This made we wonder where the air that gets trapped in radiators comes from.

I'm not looking for a specific cause for my own heating system, but a list of processes that might be the cause of air in generic central heating systems.

Comment: Air is dissolved in water, that's how fish and many other types of marine life live underwater.  As water is heated it releases some of that air.

Comment: George make that an answer, commercial systems have DA tanks so they don’t have to bleed the air.

Comment: DA means _deaerator_, which makes sense in the context of the answer. I had to look it up so I thought I'd write a comment to help others who aren't familiar with the abbreviation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Air is dissolved in water, that's how fish and many other types of marine life live underwater. As water is heated it releases some of that air. (thanks for the advice, Ed)

Comment: If the system is well-sealed bleeding should be mostly an issue when you first commission the system, or any time you have to drain and then refill it for some purpose. A system that constantly needs bleeding is almost certainly constantly leaking somewhere - and will endanger the assumption that using black iron pipe/pumps is "fine" because once the oxygen either goes out with bleeding or rusts a little bit, the rusting will stop because there's no more oxygen in the system fluid.